# Constructing micro blogging site in python? Any suggestions

Tags: python, blogs, xmpp

I want to write a micro blogging site with html frontend but xmpp backend (Instant messenger type). By this, I mean server should push all the updates to client browser and hence constant http polling is not required. I need your view and help in that.

I found 3 xmpp libraries 
1. xmppy
2. sleekxmpp
3. pyxmpp

Should i use any of these or should try from scratch. If from these which one will you suggest.

What should i do?

Comment: Use a web application framework? It's very difficult to do these things almost entirely from scratch, and you'll get better presentation and performance if you use a framework.

Comment: @rafe yes but i want more detailed ans as to how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This [slideshow](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3agaM0b0Lu-YwJ%3awww.slideshare.net/adorepump/django-and-xmpp-bosh-writing-a-real-time-web-app+django+xmpp&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) may help. The author uses django and some xmpp items that can tag along with django's authentication. This sounds pretty perfect for you.

The link is to google's cache because the original link wouldn't work for me anymore. Let me know if this is a problem.

Comment: In particular StropheJS (https://github.com/metajack/strophejs), which implements BOSH (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

try this - https://github.com/hj91/Using-XMPP-to-post-content-on-blog-sms-facebook

xmpp to wp blog poster bot code.

it takes incoming xmpp message and posts them on worpdress blogs. written in python and xmpppy library